# Operator overloading and different types

Tags: c#

I have a class Score which is  going to be heavily used in comparisons against integers.  I was planning on overloading the == operator to enable these comparisons as per the code below ?

```
public class Score
{
    public Score(int score) {
        Value = score;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Score x, int y) {
        return x != null && x.Value == y;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(int y, Score x)
    {
        return x != null && x.Value == y;
    }
}
```

Is this a sensible use of operator overloading ?

Should I be providing overloads for the LH and RH sides of the operators to allow the usage to be symmetrical ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I might go ahead and define an implicit conversion from `int` to `Score`, so that when you deal with equality, you only need to deal with a single type.

```
public static implicit operator Score(int value)
{
    return new Score { Value = value }; // or new Score(value);
}
// define bool operator ==(Score score1, Score score2)

// elsewhere 
Score score = new Score { Value = 1 };
bool isScoreOne = (score == 1);
```

And while you're defining your own `==` operator, do remember to go ahead and define `!=`, and override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Comment: I just tried this, but it does not compile -- Cannot apply operator '==' to operands of type 'int' and 'Score'

Comment: Nevermind I commented out my class == operator when I was getting rid of the other overloads.

Comment: After looking at my scenario, this is actually what I am after.  The object is likely to be relatively simple, but it will be used pervasively.

Answer (score 6):

I do think this is a strange situation to use an operator overload, but it is your call.

However, my main point is that if you overload == you will also be required to overload !=

If you then overload !=, the part where you compare x to check that it is not null using `x != null` will cause, the == operator to call the != operator.  This isn't a problem in itself, as long as this doesn't then use a == comparison, as you will have a recursive set of calls, leading to a stack-overflow.

However since a lot of people when overloading != implement it as 'not ==' - in your case this will cause a stack overflow.

Solution: particularly in overloading ==, != and Equals(), its best to use use `Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null);` when comparing to null.

Answer (score 3):

Usually when I see an overloaded operator, it comparisons of that class to itself. So if you have multiple instance variables, you would figure out how to compare the two to determine if something was equal, greater, less, etc.

I don't see why you don't just do:

```
if(myScore.value == 5)
{
 //do stuff
}
```

Comment: +1 Agreed. In *this case* the overload doesn't seem to "add value".

Comment: Seems to me that exposing the actual implementation of .value is a bad idea. What if the code changes to measure the score as a double but the comparison should be on a rounded value? You'd be able to make that implementation change without changing the usage if he used operator overloading to begin with.

Comment: Hiding the implementation of Value is a goal. @pst To some extent I am looking to reduce code clutter. If(myScore == 5) is more readable than if(myScore.Value == 5).. it is a small thing, but a consideration

Comment: @thelsdj If Value *is* part of the contract then there is no change. One can argue that "what if it was changed from an int to a float" -- I see no difference.

Answer (score 2):

"Is this a sensible use of operator overloading?"

If it makes your code easier to understand and doesn't cause problems, I would say, yes, absolutely!  There may also be other ways, but if this works for you I don't see an issue.

"Should I be providing overloads for the LH and RH sides of the operators to allow the usage to be symmetrical?"

I would argue that unless you have a specific reason to do so, in other words if you are using or need them, then you aren't gonna need it. (YAGNI) The only real exception I see is if you are writing a framework where you have a pretty good idea that someone else is gonna need it.