# Overloading == operator for null

Tags: c#, .net, null, operator-overloading, equals-operator

I have a class called `Message` which overloads these operators:

```
public static bool operator ==(Message left, Message right)
public static bool operator !=(Message left, Message right)

public static bool operator ==(Message left, string right)
public static bool operator !=(Message left, string right)

public static bool operator ==(string left, Message right)
public static bool operator !=(string left, Message right)
```

I want the `==` and `!=` operators keep comparing references of the types other than `String` and `Message` but,

```
var message = new Message();
var isNull = message == null;
```

gives me this:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Message.operator ==(Message, Message)' and 'Message.operator ==(Message, string)'

I know it's because both `Message` and `String` are reference types and they both can be `null`, but I want to be able to use `==` opreator for checking whether the message is null.

Can I overload `==` for null values? I tried overloading it for `object` and call `object.ReferenceEquals(object, object)` in the overload but that didn't help.

Comment: If you wan't to do it this way (which I do not recommend), you will have to cast `null` to one of the applicable types. `message == (string)null;` or `message == (Message)null;` should work.

Comment: @verdesmarald: Yes, that works but I was hoping to find a way for using it directly. What do you recommend btw?

Comment: Nope, as far as I am aware you can't do that if you want to have multiple `operator==`s.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provide an implementation for `operator ==(Message left, object right)` and check the type of `right` to see whether it is null, a string or a Message.

Alternatively, define an implicit constructor for Message that takes a string. See [Operator overloading and different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054894/operator-overloading-and-different-types) for an example.